# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.XmlResourceParser android.content.pm.ProviderInfo.loadXmlMetaData

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Get exception when take photo from my android app. I used Media Plugin https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin

```
   var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new StoreCameraMediaOptions
                        {
                            PhotoSize = PhotoSize.Medium,
                            Directory = "Sample",
                            Name = "test.jpg"
                        });
```

> {Java.Lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.content.res.XmlResourceParser
>   android.content.pm.ProviderInfo.loadXmlMetaData(android.content.pm.PackageManager,
>   java.lang.String)' on a null object reference   at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw ()
>   [0x0000c] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0    at
>   Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+StaticMethods.CallStaticObjectMethod
>   (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference type, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo
>   method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x00069] in
>   :0    at
>   Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallStaticObjectMethod (System.IntPtr jclass,
>   System.IntPtr jmethod, Android.Runtime.JValue* parms) [0x0000e] in
>   :0    at
>   Android.Support.V4.Content.FileProvider.GetUriForFile
>   (Android.Content.Context context, System.String authority,
>   Java.IO.File file) [0x00078] in <3e239b9681084d42bb949c1e01ef500e>:0
>   at Plugin.Media.MediaPickerActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle
>   savedInstanceState) [0x0023f] in
>   C:\projects\mediaplugin\src\Media.Plugin.Android\MediaPickerActivity.cs:162
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---   at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw ()
>   [0x0000c] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in
>   <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in
>   <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in
>   <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult ()
>   [0x00000] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0    at
>   Plugin.Media.MediaImplementation+d__16.MoveNext ()
>   [0x000c7] in
>   C:\projects\mediaplugin\src\Media.Plugin.Android\MediaImplementation.cs:119
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---   at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw ()
>   [0x0000c] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in
>   <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in
>   <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in
>   <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult ()
>   [0x00000] in <3fd174ff54b146228c505f23cf75ce71>:0    at
>   Propznet.Mobile.Features.Inventory.Helpers.UnitCreateUpdateViewModelBase+<b__32_0>d.MoveNext
>   () [0x00091] in E:\Propznet
>   Mobile\Source\Propznet.Mobile\Propznet.Mobile.Features.Inventory\Helpers\UnitCreateUpdateViewModelBase.cs:322
>   --- End of managed Java.Lang.NullPointerException stack trace --- java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.content.res.XmlResourceParser
>   android.content.pm.ProviderInfo.loadXmlMetaData(android.content.pm.PackageManager,
>   java.lang.String)' on a null object reference     at
>   android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.parsePathStrategy(FileProvider.java:583)
>     at
>   android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getPathStrategy(FileProvider.java:557)
>     at
>   android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:399)
>     at
>   md5f1b52d9f1d5d1981437e7e130649468a.MediaPickerActivity.n_onCreate(Native
>   Method)   at
>   md5f1b52d9f1d5d1981437e7e130649468a.MediaPickerActivity.onCreate(MediaPickerActivity.java:42)
>     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6259)   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1130)
>     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2382)
>     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2493)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1357)
>     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5459)     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618) }

Comment: What is your app's target version? Did you add meta-data in your android project's manifest and create a new xml called "file_path.xml"?

Comment: Android 7.0  .file_path?

Comment: Check the read me part of the lib you used, in the `ANDROID N` part.

Comment: Did these comments solved your problem?

Comment: Yes, its working

Answer (score 2):

[As james montemagno mentioned](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin)

> You MUST set your Target version to API 23+ and Compile against API
>   23+:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check the read me of the library you used, in the ANDROID N part (as stated by Grace Feng in the comments above).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, when I run the app in release mode, in debug it was ok. So I switched in properties of Android project on Android options page Liking from SDK Assemblies only to None. It solved my problem.